get Subject from InitialLdapContext
I have InitialLdapContext. My searches from it works fine. Can I retrieve Subject from this context to make some other actions under this Subject ? Smth like that:
function act(InitialLdapContext context)
{
  Subject s = context.getSubject(); //what i can write there?
  Subject.doAs(s, ....);
}

I cant find any documentation for this.
